# Query Never Finishes in app.get using MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, express

I'm having difficulty getting this portion of my node.js to run. I can output the results of the query the database in cmd. But every time I try run localhost:3000 nothing ever happens. I'm using mysql and the mysql-node api as well as express.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM games";
  db.query=(sql, (err) =>{
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }
    res.send("Able to connect to Database");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`db.query=(sql, (err) =>{` this assigns a function to `db.query`.

You should call it with `db.query(sql, (err) => {});`